# How can i show an ArrayList in ZK ui?

Tags: java, arraylist, zk

what i tried:

```
       <tabpanel>
            <listbox id="usersList" sizedByContent="true" span="true" model="@{users}">
                <listhead>
                    <listheader label="User Name"/>
                    <listheader label="gender"/>
                </listhead>
                <listitem self="@{each=users}">
                    <listcell label="@{user.userName}"/>    
                    <listcell label="@{user.gender}"/>
                </listitem>   
            </listbox>
        </tabpanel>
```

And in java side: i have ArrayList users, and if click submit after add to this list a user....but i not know how to display it in UI side....can anyone helps to me? Thanks a lot....im newbie with zk

Comment: Do you have your viewmodel declared in the zul? Don't forget tot use the id of the viewmodel in front, you use it like zscript style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tag `<template>`.
Try the following code:

```
       <tabpanel>
            <listbox id="usersList" sizedByContent="true" span="true" model="${users}">
                <listhead>
                    <listheader label="User Name"/>
                    <listheader label="gender"/>
                </listhead>
                <template name="model" var="user"> 
                    <listitem>
                        <listcell label="${user.userName}"/>    
                        <listcell label="${user.gender}"/>
                    </listitem>   
                </template>
            </listbox>
        </tabpanel>
```

But if your list changes while the application is running, you can use `@load(users)` instead of `${users}`